# Task keeping Form instance open?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a Windows form which opens another form. In the secondary form it starts a Task asynchronously. If the user starts the task and then cancels it and quickly closes the form, the form is Disposed and set to null however when the task comes back from being cancelled I still get a MessageBox.Show happen

```
public class MyMainForm : Form
{
  public void OpenChildForm()
  {
     MyChildForm form = new MyChildForm();
     form.ShowDialog();
     form.Dispose();
     form = null;
  }
}

public class MyChildForm : Form
{

  private CancellationTokenSource MyTokensource;
  private Task task; 


  public void StartTask()
  {
     MyTokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(MyTokensource.Token), MyTokensource.Token);
  }

  public void MyMethod(CancellationToken token)
  {
      var result = StaticClass.DoSomethingLengthy(token);  //The cancel make take a couple of seconds to return here
      if (result == Cancelled)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
         UpdateLabel("Cancelled")
       }
  }

  public void ButtonClose_Click()
  { 
    if (task != null && !task.IsCompleted)
    {
      MyTokensource.Cancel();
    }
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the form is Disposed and set to null however when the task comes back from being cancelled I still get a MessageBox.Show happen

Setting the variable that is a reference to the form to null, and even calling Dispose() on the form, does not actually *destroy* the form.  The Task is still executing until it's cancelled (`CancellationTokenSource` is designed as a cooperative model for cancellation).

As such, you need to explicitly handle the code path that occurs when the task is cancelled.  This may be as simple as checking to see if you're disposed already, ie:

```
if (this.IsDisposed)
    return; // Just break out if we canceled and shut down

// Your other code....
if (result == Cancelled)
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
```

Comment: That worked although I dont get why you say its not destroyed event though I call dispose. I guess because GC has not kicked in!

Comment: @Jon Dispose **has no direct effect on memory (necessarily)** or any managed objects.  It's nothing but a method, that (by convention) is used to release native resources.  It has zero effect on memory or objects allocated and managed by the CLR.  See: http://reedcopsey.com/series/idisposable/  Granted, the "resource" in question could be memory, but it could be anything else, as well (or nothing).

Answer (score 2):

This makes sense. The `Task` is off executing asynchronously, its execution lifetime is not tied to the lifetime of the `Form`. You will just need to add an explicit check to make sure you don't show the `MessageBox` if the `Form` is already being/has been disposed of:

```
if(result == Cancelled
            &&
   !(this.Disposing
           ||
    this.IsDisposed))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't things like the UpdateLabel fall over because I would have thought the label wouldn't have existed etc

Comment: Shouldn't this read `&& !(this.Disposing || this.IsDisposed)`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yep, forgot my not. Updating sample.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to watch out for: make sure you're not calling `StartTask()` more than one time.

If so, you end up with multiple asynchronous tasks, and with multiple instances of  `CancellationTokenSource` (out of which only one is still referred by the form).

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the form is still there, even though the window may not be visible. To make sure that the `MessageBox` is not shown after the form has been closed, add an event to `OnClosing` and set a member variable `m_formClosed` to `true`. Show the message only when the member variable is `false`.

```
if (result == Cancelled && !m_formClosed)
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
```

Answer (score 0):

The GC may not have collected the form, despite you calling `Dispose()` and setting the reference to null.  This is normal, since the GC is non-deterministic.

Due to the way `IDisposable` is implemented, you can check the `IsDisposed` and `IsDisposing` properties on the form to see if the `Dispose()` method has already been called or is in the process of being run.